Azure copy data tool unexpected foreach error
I have a pipeline created by the copy data tool that does a bulk insert in a dedicated SQL pool in synapse. It works fine, but when I encapsulate it in a more complex pipeline with the execute pipeline action I get the following error:

Operation on target ForEach_fzr failed: The execution of template action 'MainForEach_fzr' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@pipeline().parameters.cw_items' is of type 'String'. The result must be a valid array.

The parameters are the same as the original pipeline, I don't understand the error and I have no clue how to fix it.


ForEach activity expects an array to iterate over,but the value provided in @pipeline().parameters.cw_items is a string instead that may be the reason to get above error. To resolve the error, change the parameter @pipeline().parameters.cw_items type to array from string, and provide array of values as shown below:

Then the pipeline will execute successfully without any error.
